# Flutter thumb icons not showing

Tags: flutter

I try to use icons within my switch in flutter. I can only see the default switch and it does not show the x and the check icon when I use the switch.

I have tried:

```
     final MaterialStateProperty<Icon?> thumbIcon =
          MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Icon?>(
        (Set<MaterialState> states) {
          if (states.contains(MaterialState.selected)) {
            return const Icon(Icons.check);
          }
          return const Icon(Icons.close);
        },
      );
    
         @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        Switch(
          thumbIcon: thumbIcon,
          value: globals.mode,
          onChanged: (bool value) {
            setState(() {
              globals.mode = value;
            });
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

and:

```
    @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        Switch(
          thumbIcon: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Icon?>(
    (Set<MaterialState> states) {
      if (states.contains(MaterialState.selected)) {
        return const Icon(Icons.check);
      }
      return const Icon(Icons.close);
    },
  ),
          value: globals.mode,
          onChanged: (bool value) {
            setState(() {
              globals.mode = value;
            });
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

Question edited with widget build added.
Thanks for answers!

Comment: Could you provide a full code snippet of your Widget?

Comment: Added! @KęstutisRamulionis

Comment: I tried your first code, it's working on my end. Do you have any values set for switch-related style on your theme?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of your codes are correct. Just simply add `useMaterial3: true` to your MaterialApp

```
MaterialApp(
  theme: ThemeData(useMaterial3: true),
  // other codes
```